# Days/Months/Years between two dates

Tags: perl, date, time, date-arithmetic

I have two dates. One retrieved from the table from other application in format YYYYMMDD and the second date is local time and I need Days/Months/Years between these two dates.

I tried this

```
  my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($expi, "%Y %m %d"); #First date
  my $today = Time::Piece->new; #Localtime

  my $diff = $t - $today; 
  print $diff;
```

but this gives me some gibberish numbers.

variable $t = Fri Dec 31 00:00:00 9999

variable $today = Wed Feb 19 14:40:55 2020

OUTPUT: 251820094888

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please [edit] and include example data and output?

Comment: It's recommended to use Time::Piece::localtime instead of Time::Piece->new (they are the same, but the first makes it more obvious that you are retrieving the time in the system time zone not UTC).

Comment: Note that Time::Piece->strptime parses the date in UTC, not localtime. To parse it as localtime you can do `Time::Piece::localtime->strptime` (see [this issue](https://github.com/Dual-Life/Time-Piece/issues/44))

Comment: More importantly, `Time::Piece->new` isn't local time or today. It's the current UTC time (which might a different date than the local time). You want `Time::Piece::localtime` for the local time. Not sure how to get local date ("today").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time::Piece can at-most get you the difference in seconds, and there's no way to convert that into months, days, etc.

```
use DateTime                   qw( );
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%Y%m%d',
   time_zone => 'floating',
   on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $today =
   DateTime
   ->now( time_zone => 'local' )
   ->set_time_zone('floating')
   ->truncate( to => 'day' );

my $dt = $format->parse_datetime('20200101');

my $diff = $today - $dt;

printf("%d years, %d months and %d days\n", $diff->in_units(qw( years months days )));
```

Output:

```
0 years, 1 months and 18 days
```